# View Cookies in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, privacy, cookies

If you use Mozilla Firefox in the "never remember history" setting, how can one see which cookies are currently saved (and possibly delete specific ones)? The answer I've heard is to look in Preferences -> Tools, but this is the screen shot of that tab, and there is no list of cookies here:

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As of Firefox 61, access to cookies has been removed from regular end user UI. You can still see and modify them via Developer Tools however:

- Press Ctrl+Shift+I (Cmd+Option+I on macOS) to open Developer Tools.
- Click the heading of the "Storage" tab.
- On the left side of the panel, make sure to select the desired site under "Cookies." If the site has third-party frames, you can also see cookies set by these frames by selecting the right site.
- You can delete cookies via context menu. You can also double-click the value to modify it.

#### Original answer, for reference

The Page Info dialog lets you view cookies - from the context menu on a page choose "View Page Info", go to the "Security" tab and click "View Cookies". By default it will only show the cookies for the current page but you can remove the search string and it will show all cookies. If you want it a bit more comfortable you can install the [View Cookies extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/view-cookies/).

Comment: That extension is now removed from Firefox addons website.

Comment: This answer should add the details from the more up-voted answer, and it would be a very comprehensive solution. Additionally, the fact that the extension was removed is a definite detractor from this answer.

Comment: The Page Info dialog no longer has this option as far as I can tell (Firefox 62.0). It lets you clear the cookies but not look at them.

Comment: @SorenBjornstad: Yes, I've updated this answer for new Firefox versions.

Comment: is there a way to export them?

Comment: Mozilla "We totally value privacy and user freedom" Firefox, everyone

Comment: @JonathanBaldwin, a doubleplusgood example of newspeak that is

Comment: The problem is that this requires actually going to the site which might not be possible for any number of reasons, but more importantly, going to the site might very well modify the data. I don't understand why they removed the ability to view cookies out-of-band. 

Comment: @Synetech: Under about:preferences#privacy you can click "Manage data" which will list all the sites along with the number of cookies stored. But it will no longer show you the actual values, presumably to keep this UI simple.

Comment: @WladimirPalant, that's the problem, it used to show you values and let you delete individual cookies, now it only shows you the sites and lets you only delete _everything_. The "simple" UI is completely useless. They assume every domain hosts only a single site and that all cookies are related to a single entity which is just not true (eg Geocities/ISP hosts, etc). Even if it were true, it's still useless because you might not want to delete everything. For example, you might want to only delete the cookies for a single game on Kongregate, not all of them.

Answer (score 14):

### Quick Solution:

You can manage cookies by going to the following address*:

```
chrome://browser/content/preferences/cookies.xul
```

<sub>*Domains have been removed from the screenshot</sub>

[image: Cookies]

---

### Alternatively...

Setting Firefox to `Never remember history` will hide the link or button to manage cookies. To enable the button, you must choose `Remember history` or `Use custom settings for history` as @kreemoweet mentioned.

[image: Remember history]

[image: Custom settings]

Comment: This doesn't work anymore (Firefox 62.0) -- the page doesn't exist.

Comment: This doesn't work on Firefox 63 on mac os High Sierra. I get an error: "File not found"

Comment: this *does* work on Firefox 52 (on RHEL 7.4) and I'm actually quite surprised that Firefox implements a `chrome://` URL scheme

Comment: The `chrome://` URL scheme refers to the _application_ look-and-feel.  It is unrelated to and was in use well before the similarly named browser by Google.

Answer (score 6):

By far, to me, this seems the best way to view and delete cookies in the Firefox since it shows some details which are not available in the other methods - e.g. if a field in a cookie is `httpOnly` or not will be visible this way.

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open **Firefox Developer Tools**.
2. Go to **Storage** tab.
3. From the left pane, expand **Cookies** node. Under this node you can see a list of Websites that have cookies stored on your device.
4. Select one Website and see its cookies on the right pane with their details. From here you can delete every individual cookie.

HTH

Comment: As of 2018-06, or Firefox version 60 this is the only option. Page Info, chrome:URI, preferences/privacy and most of plugins will not show individual cookies.

Comment: Worked great on Firefox 63 on Mac OS High Sierra.

Comment: The problem is that this requires actually going to the site which might not be possible for any number of reasons, but more importantly, going to the site might very well modify the data. I don't understand why they removed the ability to view cookies out-of-band. 

Comment: @Synetech When you visit the site and open the developer tools afterwards, any new modifications will be there. So, other than probable impossibility of going to the site, data modification should not be a serious problem I guess. I, too, don't understand why they removed the ability to view the cookies out-of-band.

Comment: `When you visit the site and open the developer tools afterwards, any new modifications will be there.` @Kamran That's my point. By going to the site, you risk the data getting modified. It's no longer possible to view the data without risking it being modified from within the browser itself. :-\

Comment: "a list of Websites that have cookies stored on your device" - to be clear, this is only a list of sites/domains (and associated cookies) that have set cookies as a result of visiting the currently viewed website. It's not a list of _all_ websites that have cookies stored on your device.

Answer (score 5):

### Access the Cookie Database

You can query the cookie DB directly using SQLite; you'll have all the power of SQL at your fingertips.

First, find the Firefox profile directory. Type `about:support` in the URL bar. Look for "Profile Folder" in the table. Open a terminal and change to that directory.

```
$ cd ~/.mozilla/firefox/fw6qr.default-1234567
```

Close Firefox to unlock the cookie DB. Then open the cookie DB using SQLite.

```
$ sqlite3 cookies.sqlite
sqlite> .tables
moz_cookies
sqlite> -- view cookie table schema
sqlite> .schema moz_cookies
sqlite> -- example cookie query
sqlite> SELECT host, name, value FROM moz_cookies ORDER BY host;
sqlite> -- delete tracking cookies
sqlite> DELETE FROM moz_cookies WHERE host LIKE '%googleadservices.com';
```

#### Pro Tip

The cool thing about accessing the cookie database directly is that you can programatically delete nefarious or annoying cookies. Just wrap the invocation to Firefox in a script. After Firefox terminates, then cleanse your cookies.

Comment: Great tip. One thing though: one does not have to close Firefox. You can just copy the SQLite db file to some temporary location and then open it.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you could find [Cookie Manager+](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-manager-plus/) add-on useful. In particular, "Delete and block" command there.

Comment: That looks interesting. Can add-on's like this leak information. i.e., am I giving the information about the cookies to the author of cookie manager+, or is it all working in a sand box?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Firecookie](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firecookie/?src=search) addon.

Comment: Firecookie is not compatible with the firefox on the beta channel, so I haven't tried it yet, but it looks good. They should update it to make it compatible with 11.0, if you are or know the developer.

Answer (score 0):

In Private Browsing you do not have cookies stored, so there's nothing to see.
Details at: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Private-Browsing. 
Edit to add:
If you have pre-existing cookies you want to look over, you can change the
drop-down box setting to "use custom settings for history", which will cause
a number of additional settings to appear below, among which is a button to
"View Cookies".

Comment: The question is not asking about Private Browsing. The user has set Firefox to 'never remember history'. This preference keeps any old history, cookies, etc, but in the future, will not store any history.

Comment: Good catch! That is the reason why the 'show/remove cookies' link is missing. :)

Comment: I think it still saves cookies for the length of the session. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to log in to gmail, and everythime you open a link, you would have to log back in. Its just that the cookies are deleted when you quit the application.

Answer (score 0):

**The list of cookies is here (any plugin is needed) :**

Preference -> Tools -> Privacy -> Historic -> on the combo box is selected : "Use custom settings for historic"
They are few checkbox underneath and a button named: "Display Cookies.."

When a click under this button a window pops with all the currents cookies inside, which could be deleted

I'm using FireFox 10.0 and I'm able to see which cookies are currently saved (and possibly delete specific ones).

Comment: Strangely, that button is only displayed with the `Use custom settings for history` setting. It is not displayed when `Never remember history` is selected.

Answer (score 0):

The only built-in way at the moment is to go through the Developer-Tools which requires actually going to the site (assuming that's even possible), but even then, that means it's possible/likely that when you do, the site will **modify the cookies**. Unfortunately, for some reason, the Firefox developers decided to remove the built-in ability to view cookies out-of-band from the browser itself.

If you want to view cookies for a site without going to it (e.g., it's down, no Internet access, you want to recover the data, do mild forensics, etc.), currently the only option is to use a third-party utility. Fortunately [Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) is a reliable, trusted source of tools and his [MZCookiesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mzcv.html) utility is ideal for this purpose.

`Some features include:
 • View and delete cookies without even closing the browser
 • Provides useful sorting, search, and filtering functions
 • Gives instant access to full meta-data about the cookies
 • Makes it easy to work with cookies of different profiles
 • Can let you access and edit with offline/backup profiles
 • Has builtin backup and restore functions for cookie file
 • Manually select a different "cookies.sqlite" file to use`

Comment: unrelated, but in your bio you said you will not be helping future users and said sorry to the 'non-existent' future users for not helping. Here I am forgiving you for the sorry you said back, for the endeavor you are doing now.

Comment: (Sometimes I run into issues myself and find my way back onto SE sites—which is unavoidable now. If I end up finding a solution that isn't listed, then I'll probably share it. I'm just not actively "playing" the StackExchange MMOG anymore; I don't care about medals and points.)