# How can I identify what cookies a site needs using Firefox?

Tags: firefox, cookies

I want to whitelist a site that uses cookies in a complex way. Unfortunately I can't figure out what domain names to whitelist.

When I try to go the site in Firefox, I get this error:

> The web site is not redirecting properly. This problem can be caused by refusing cookies.

If I set browser options to accept all cookies, then the web site appears correctly. However, if I then go to the "Manage Data..." option of the Options screen and sort cookies by time, it does NOT show any cookies being "used" within the last few minutes. So, for some reason, whatever cookies are being used are not showing up in this informational dialog.

How can I get the cookie information for the site in Firefox?

Note that the information I need is ALL cookies, sorted by time, not just the cookies for a particular domain, because the web site is apparently redirecting through intermediary domains that seem to be setting the cookies that are getting missed.

Comment: Can you share the site's address?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [View Cookies in Mozilla Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/392176/view-cookies-in-mozilla-firefox)

Comment: @EduardoTrápani It requires a login to access it, so you would not be able to test it.

Comment: @Berend No, see the last paragraph in my question.

Comment: @TylerDurden Can you open the network inspector (press F12, go on "Network" tab) and then browse the website. Every request and it's response should appear. Does it list requests to other domains ?

Answer (score 2):

To identify those cookies in Firefox you can open the [Storage Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector) by pressing Shift+F9.

You then load the page and monitor just the cookies (choose `Cookies` on the left side of the Storage Inspector UI).

Answer (score 1):

Using [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) you can have the list of all domains your webpage is connecting to.

As mentioned in a [previous post](https://superuser.com/a/1362716/1107715), these domains may try to download their own cookies on your computer.